# Invalid form location when placing form in table header

Tags: html, eclipse, forms, html-table, tableheader

I am using (successfully) the header of my HTML tables as a form.  This form is used to filter the table rows below and works great.   Here is an example :

```
<table class="tableMedium">
    <tr>
        <form name="fiterRoles" action="<c:url value="/roles/filteredList" />" method="POST">
            <th>Name<br/>
                <input type="text" id="nameFilter" name="nameFilter" value="${nameFilter}" placeholder="Search" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="width: 100%;"/>
            </th>
            <th>Description<br/>
                <input type="text" name="descriptionFilter" value="${descriptionFilter}" placeholder="Search" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="width: 100%;"/>
            </th>
            <th width="${hasEditRights eq true ? '22%' : '6%'}">Controls<br/>
                <a class="buttonLink" href="<c:url value='/roles/list' />" title="Reset Filters">
                    <img src="${cp}/resources/images/resetFilters.png" height="20" width="20"/>
                </a>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${hasEditRights eq true}">
                        <a class="buttonLink" href="<c:url value='/roles/newRole' />" title="Add Role">
                            <img src="${cp}/resources/images/addIcon.png" height="20" width="20"/>
                        </a>
                    </c:when>
                </c:choose>
            </th>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The only issue is that Eclipse keeps telling me this is an invalid location for a form.  The page works perfectly but it seems HTML5 does not allow this.  I noticed as I copy-pasted the example that this table has no `<thead>` tag but others using the same style of header-form have it and Eclipse is still not happy.  I have tried moving the `<form>` tags outside of said `<thead>` tag with no success.

Short of disabling the warning in Eclipse, is there something I can do for this code to become valid?

Comment: Place the entire table inside the form tag. The complaint is that the form tag appears in the middle of the table rendering elements, and though it *may* output correctly, the placement is technically out of order.

Comment: The table is not part of the form, the table header IS a form.  The table has rows with data in them, the header is just used as a form for filtering purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?  A rendered table has: `<table><tr><th></th>...(and more)...<th></th></tr></table>`  which can also have other table elements such as `<thead>, <tbody>, <tfoot> <td>...` (among others) ... and not have stray `<form>` elements mixed in-between those, based on the "Content Model" [described here](http://w3c.github.io/html/tabular-data.html#the-table-element). If you'd like to have a form within a table, I've seen it done as: `<table><tr><td><form>...(form content)...</form></td></tr></table>`, as a simplified example.

Comment: ...(continued) Also know that the same information source claims: `Tables should not be used as layout aids.` Personally, I prefer `<div>` or `<fieldset>` sections within a `<form>` to have a `<table>`-less design. Makes for less 'mess' to deal with. See some of the table-less form examples [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-form-element)

Comment: A form can contain a table, and a table cell can contain a form. You have no other options. Choose one or the other. Also, you say "The page works perfectly", but that's just the result of the browser's error handling you see happening. Other browsers may handle this error differently. And your last question, "Short of disabling the warning in Eclipse, is there something I can do for this code to become valid?" sounds like you think the code will become valid by turning off warnings. That is not how it works.

Comment: I know that turning off the warning doesn't magically result in valid code.  My sentence wasn't formulated the best i'll admit.  What i meant was more along the lines of : I don't want to disable warnings, is there a way to have a table header also be a form.  I would really hate to have to place the filtering form above the table in 60+ JSP pages but if that's the only way to have valid HTML i will.

Comment: Thinking about the first comment again, if I place the form tag outside the table element it should work.  My goal is for the header to be a form but the only inputs are in the header, the rows should be ignored by the form.  I will give this a shot and see if it's still functional.

Comment: @PaulT. please post an answer so i can mark it accepted, placing the entire table inside the form results in valid HTML and does not affect my header filtering functionality.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the entire table inside the form tag. The complaint is that the form tag appears in the middle of the table rendering elements, and though it *may* output correctly, the placement is technically out of order.

A table can be inside a form element:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <!-- other table related elements -->
  </table>
</form>
```

...or the form can be inside a table cell:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <!-- form content -->
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- other table related elements -->
</table>
```

Keep in mind though, that it would be better to avoid tables as "layout aids", as previously mentioned.